# Twilio API call retrying limit

Tags: twilio

I was trying to implement voice call using Twilio API(Using node twilio wrapper) in which it would require to retry x number of times if call not answered. It seems that if i ignore call from Twilio, it keeps trying automatically. So, is there any way i can set the retying limit to particular number of times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi I am having same problem too. How did you fix it

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

As far as I know we do not have any auto-retry behavior built into Twilio, so its odd that you are seeing this behavior.  I'd suggest sending an email over to help [at] twilio.com with some example CallSids.  Our awesome support team can work directly with you to help figure out whats going on.

Hope that helps.